# Errors cloning a git repo

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I am new to Git and for a class assignment I need to clone a repo set up by the instructor as a first step of about 50 this week. His instructions are to:

```
mkdir -p ${HOME}/cpsc59700
cd ${HOME}/cpsc59700
git clone git@github.com: lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git tu2
cd tu2
TUTROOT=${PWD}
```

He says "the first argument specifies the remote repositoy in GitHub you would like to clone and the second argument specifies the name to give to the new local repository." I am guessing "lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git" is the remote repo while "tu2" is the local repo.

Each time I try to run the git clone command I am met with the following error:

> fatal: Too many arguments

If I leave off the tu2 argument I get the following error:

> Cloning into 'lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git'...
>   Enter passphrase for key '/c/user/Brian/.ssh/id_rsa':

When I enter the passphrase that I used for creating the ssh key I get the following error:

> ERROR: Repository not found.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
>   
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I have access to the repo when I log in to Github.com. Also, when I try using Git Desktop, I can clone the repo which is what confuses me. I have emailed the teacher as it is an online class but so far (3 days later), I have not heard back from him. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the space after the domain name, like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git tu2
```

The space causes `lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git` to be your second argument and `tu2` the third one, that's way the error says "too many arguments".

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This worked perfectly. I just finished working through the assignment and it appears there were a few other typos in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are able to make directory and go inside it. Then follow following step

1) Go to following link.

https://github.com/lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git

[image]

2) Click on copy to clip board button. 
3) Open your terminal and navigate to your directory where your want to get the clone.

4) Then type git clone **https://github.com/lewisu-research-compsci/assign0-git.git**